# docker-compose Error Cannot start service mongo: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint

Tags: windows, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm setting up grandnode with mondodb in docker using docker compose.

***docker-compose.yml***

```
    version: "3.6"

    services:
      mongo:
        image: mongo:3.6
        volumes:
          - mongo_data_db:/data/db
          - mongo_data_configdb:/data/configdb
        ports:
          - 27017:27017
      grandnode:
        image: grandnode/grandnode:4.10
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
          - mongo

    volumes:
      mongo_data_db:
        external: true
      mongo_data_configdb:
        external: true
```

Getting below error while using the docker-compose.

```
E:\docker\grandnode>docker-compose up
Creating network "grandnode_default" with the default driver
Creating grandnode_mongo_1 ... error

ERROR: for grandnode_mongo_1 Cannot start service mongo: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint grandnode_mongo_1 (1e54342c07b093e32189aad487927f226b3ed0d1b6bdf7413588377b0e99bc2c): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:27017:tcp:172.20.0.2:27017: input/output error

ERROR: for mongo Cannot start service mongo: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint grandnode_mongo_1 (1e54342c07b093e32189aad487927f226b3ed0d1b6bdf7413588377b0e99bc2c): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:27017:tcp:172.20.0.2:27017: input/output error
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: Does it give any different error when you remove `external: true` from the volumes?

Comment: seems like a problem with port 27017 - did you make sure its not used?

Comment: @PriidikVaikla No, same error

Comment: @Efrat Removed  ports:
      - 27017:27017, but still getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because the Shared Drives were unchecked.

- Check the drives required
- Click Apply
- Restart Docker

This will fix the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It happened to me, in Xubuntu 20.04.
The problem was that I had mongod running in my computer.
Stopping mongod was the solution for me.

I did this:

```
sudo systemctl stop mongod
```

Check that mongod was stopped with:

```
systemctl status mongod | grep Active
```

The output of this command should be:

```
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Then, executed again this:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to connect to your MongoDB instance from your local host, you don't need that port mapping "27017:27017".
Both services are on the same network and will see each other anyway. Grandnode can connect to MongoDB at mongo:27017

Comment: Removed it, but still getting error, 

ERROR: for 10d29f3ab611_grandnode_grandnode_1  Cannot start service grandnode: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint grandnode_grandnode_1 (53feafa5d849557f2f84ef95627e9a6f4fd3756bc45f27b5e7db5e48b5a65d5d): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:8080:tcp:172.20.0.3:8080: input/output error

Comment: @KishoreSahasranaman That is still progress. Are you sure nothing is running on 8080 already? Maybe another container (try docker ps and check the ports) or another application on host?

Comment: seems like occupied ports.
run `sudo fuser -n tcp -k 8080` a few times untill you get no output.
then re-run `docker-compose up`

Comment: @Efrat He is on Windows (You can see it from the post)

Comment: @Mihai Yes, there is nothing hosted in 8080. even checked with 'netstat -a -b'

Comment: @KishoreSahasranaman Can you just change 8080 to 80080? There are some things that puzzle me: looks like a busy port, you are on Windows and the mkdir command looks like Linux. Changing the host port would help understand if it is a port issue or a platform issue.

Comment: @Mihai I tried with 60080, as 80080 is out of port range. 
But still am getting the same error

Comment: @KishoreSahasranaman Then indeed is a platform issue. Can you please check this post and see if it applies to your situation: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/204#issuecomment-303461340

Answer (score 0):

stop your MongoDB server from your OS.

for linux

```
sudo systemctl stop mongod
```

if this still doesn't work then uninstall MongoDB from the local machine and run docker compose once again

Answer (score 0):

for Linux user

sudo systemctl stop MongoDB

sudo docker-compose up -d

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).